# How to extend/concatenate two iterators in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, iterator

I want concatenate two iterators in an efficient way.

Suppose we have two iterators (in Python3)

```
l1 = range(10)      # iterator over 0, 1, ..., 9
l2 = range(10, 20)  # iterator over 10, 11, ..., 19
```

If we convert them to lists, it is easy to concatenate like

```
y = list(l1) + list(l2)  # 0, 1, ,..., 19
```

However, this can be not efficient.

I would like to do something like

```
y_iter = l1 + l2  # this does not work
```

What is the good way to do this in Python3?

Comment: See the docs for `itertools.chain()`.

Comment: `range` objects aren't iterators.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain
y_iter = chain(l1, l2)
```

It yields all the items from `l1` and then all the items from `l2`. Effectively concatenating the sequence of yielded items. In the process it consumes both.

Answer (score 5):

you can use the chain() function provided by the itertools

itertools.chain()