# Invalid syntax of FOR loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

Can anybody explain me why this line gives me an error

```
['foo', 'foo_{}'.format(s) for s in range(0,5)]
```

But it works properly when I do like these:

```
['foo_{}'.format(s) for s in range(0,5)]
```

or even

```
['foo', ['foo_{}'.format(s) for s in range(0,5)]]
```

and it gives me memory allocation when I do like this:

```
['foo', ('foo_{}'.format(s) for s in range(0,5))]
```

I am learning and a newbie in Python and I am very curious 
why it produces me "**Invalid Syntax**" when I try this line of code

```
['foo', 'foo_{}'.format(s) for s in range(0,5)]
```

Is there an alternative way to have an output of

```
Output: ['foo','foo_0','foo_1','foo_2','foo_3','foo_4']
```

without to do manually code?

Cheers!

Comment: ['foo'] + ['foo_{}'.format(s) for s in range(0,5)] is what I would use

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116557/how-to-extend-concatenate-two-iterators-in-python

Comment: @Skirrebattie Thank you for your alternative way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
['foo_{}'.format(s) for s in range(0,5)]
```

The above implementation is List Comprehensions. You can check detail here, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

However by doing this: `['foo', 'foo_{}'.format(s) for s in range(0,5)]` you are breaking List Comprehension implementation and actually you are defining a list whose first member is `'foo'` and the other is`'foo_{}'.format(s) for s in range(0,5)`

Since the second member is neither a proper list element nor List Comprehensions syntax error is occured

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the source. This is very helpful. Think I should have a further study on that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
[('foo', 'foo_{}'.format(s)) for s in range(0,5)]
```

I suspect this is because Python sees `['foo', 'foo_{}'.format(s)` and thinks it's just a list. Then it sees `for` and is suddenly confused.

If you wrap `'foo', 'foo_{}'.format(s)` in parentheses it removes the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `a for b in c` does not allow an implicit `tuple` in `a` (comma-separated expressions not enclosed in parentheses). That forces you to explicitly choose what exactly is combined by the comma:

```
[('foo', 'foo_{}'.format(s)) for s in range(0,5)]
# [('foo', 'foo_0'), ('foo', 'foo_1'), ('foo', 'foo_2'), ('foo', 'foo_3'), ('foo', 'foo_4')]
['foo', ('foo_{}'.format(s) for s in range(0,5))]
# ['foo', <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fc2d41daca8>]
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your answer :D