# Python Regular Expression re.finditer 2 matches

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

Im looking to use single function to match for multiple values that can be used within another function.

I can get below to work with single regex value, looking for advise to match on second regex "regex2"

Working ---

```
def parse_desc(description):
    regex = r"^Created on\((.*?)\) for (.*?) "
    matches = re.finditer(regex, description, re.MULTILINE)
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
        return match.groups()
    return '', ''
```

Proposed --- trying to find match for both "Created on" and "Copied On"

```
def pass_desc(description):
    regex = r"^Created on\((.*?)\) for (.*?) "
    regex2 = r"^(.*?)Copied on (.*?) "
    matches = re.finditer(regex, description, re.MULTILINE) or re.finditer(regex2, description, re.MULTILINE)
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
        return match.groups()
    return '', ''
```

I can get both regexs to work as single functions

Comment: write a new regex that is the combination of the two with a `|` perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see why this approach won't work, try to execute in the interpreter `1 or 2`. This behavior is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth).

I would search both patterns individually, and then go over them in two subsequent `for` loops. If you need one single iterator object, it should be possible to use

```py
from itertools import chain
y_iter = chain(l1, l2)
```

to chain both iterator objects together.

Comment: so in my case y_iter = chain(regex, regex2) , I could then call y_iter. trying to figure out how to relate to above single function.

Comment: def parse_description(description):
    regex = r"^Created on\((.*?)\) for (.*?) "
    regex2 = r"^(.*?)Copied on (.*?) "
    matches = re.finditer(regex, description, re.MULTILINE)
    matches2 = re.finditer(regex2, description, re.MULTILINE)

    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
        return match.groups()
    return '', ''
    
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches2):
        return match.groups()
    return '', ''

Comment: I was able to get it working thanks to your comment and link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116557/how-to-extend-concatenate-two-iterators-in-python/44116611

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two regular expressions with an `|` (or). Now there will be 4 groups returned for each match, two of which will be `None` depending upon what was matched. Even though you had a `for` loop, you were issuing a `return` after retrieving the first match, and that was not correct. The updated code, which uses a *list comprehension* to return *all* the matches:

import re

```
def pass_desc(description):
    regex12 = r"^Created on\((.*?)\) for (.*?) |^(.*?)Copied on (.*?) "
    return [match.groups() for match in re.finditer(regex12, description, re.MULTILINE)]

print(pass_desc('Created on(Tuesday) for Mary \nIt was Copied on Friday for Sally.'))
```

Prints:

```
[('Tuesday', 'Mary', None, None), (None, None, 'It was ', 'Friday')]
```

Comment: now getting error , when trying this function.    "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)" @Booboo

Comment: What was the input text that caused the error and specifically what line of code threw the error?

Comment: was able to get it working using from itertools import chain
y_iter = chain(l1, l2)

Answer (score 0):

```
def pass_desc(description):
    regex = r"^Created on\((.*?)\) for (.*?) "
    regex2 = r"^(.*?)Copied on (.*?) "
    matches = re.finditer(regex, description, re.MULTILINE)
    matches2 = re.finditer(regex2, description, re.MULTILINE)

    from itertools import chain
    y_iter = chain(matches, matches2)

    for matchNum, match in enumerate(y_iter):
        return match.groups()
    return '', ''
```