# How to concatenate map objects without transforming them in iterables in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following code:

```
def square(x):
    return x**2


def cube(x):
    return x**3


in1 = [0, 2, 3]
in2 = [2, 1, 9]

y1 = map(square, in1)
y2 = map(cube, in2)
```

How to concatenate the two maps objects without explicitly converting the iterators `y1` and `y2` into iterables?

Comment: "convert into iterables" doesn't really make sense, as they're already iterables.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```py
import itertools
def square(x):
    return x**2


def cube(x):
    return x**3


in1 = [0, 2, 3]
in2 = [2, 1, 9]

y1 = map(square, in1)
y2 = map(cube, in2)

y1_y2 = itertools.chain(y1, y2)

print(list(y1_y2))
# [0, 4, 9, 8, 1, 729]
```

Related answer: [How to extend/concatenate two iterators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116557)